# Set html in Angular2 dialog

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I am using this [library](https://github.com/dvorapa/dialog-dart) to make dialogs. I want to set my own HTML in dialog. I want to do it from template. I made it so :

```
TemplateElement templateElement = new TemplateElement()
      ..appendHtml('Hello [username]')
      ..setAttribute('username', 'USER');
```

Then:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(
        [templateElement],
        "Sample title", true,
        'Cancel', 'Ок');
```

And have this in html on page:

```
    <template username="USER">
        Hello [username]    
    </template>
```

So I need to convert TemplateElement to HtmlElement. I don't understand, how can I do it.

Comment: Does that library support custom HTML content ? I did not see any traces of this in de documentation...

Comment: Looked like text only to me. I just had a brief look.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer , I add successfully a file upload via `FileUploadInputElement`. Dialog constructor has as 1st element List<Node>. I need method, that separate .html file to List<KinfOfSomeElement>

Comment: Not exactly sure why you are using that library, dont completely understand what you are saying but you can easily add html into another element by setting the attribute `[innerHTML]="yourHtmlVariable"`

Comment: @ribsies I wanted to make modal dialog to allow uploading some files to server. There is only one library on dart, that can help me. I need only set custom HTML to this. I am sure, that it's possible

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Why did you not say, that you have perfect Modal Box library on github? I think, I should use it! Thanks :D

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Oh, It isn't working :-(

Comment: I don't know about a modal library.